# JSONP check header response

Tags: http-headers, cross-domain, jsonp

if I get data from an external website in JSONP form, how do I access the http header response? I have heard this may be difficult but my experience is that everything is possible.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: https://twitter.com/Schabse/status/343043352889024513

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

This is completely impossible.

The whole point of JSONP is to bypass the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) by passing a result through executable Javascript code.
Other than JS code generated by the remote server, you cannot get any information.

Comment: If that is so, then why can I manually view the response in a browser like chrome? The response is sent in some form.

Comment: @user2104778: Yes, but it is not accessible from Javascript for security reasons.

Comment: is it accessible in any other language or any other way.

Comment: @user2104778: It is accessible in any environment that does not have the same-origin policy (eg, cross-domain AJAX, server-side code)

Comment: btw, I think the answer to your twitter question - 'I've never understood people who ask "I know this is blocked for security reasons, but there must be a way to get it"' - is simple. This is basically a type of question that all inventors ask, namely "how can I achieve this currently unachievable task". We are lucky that they do ask because the end result is advancement.

Comment: anyway, I appreciate your insight.

Comment: @user2104778: **No**.  The end result is _a security hole_, which must then be fixed.  It's impossible for a reason.

Comment: On the other hand, JSONP itself is an answer to that exact question.